# 10 coins probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We throw 10 coins, what is the probability that one is heads and nine of them are tails. What is the difference if we throw them all at once or one by one.

My thought process:

If we throw them all at once:
We need to get the number of all combinations in the denominator, so that would be: $\frac{10(10-1)}{2}$, the number of valid combinations for us is if we throw them all at once would then be only one, so we would get: $P(\text{All at once})=\frac{1}{45}$

If we throw them one by one, then: $P(\text{One by one})=\frac{10}{2^{10}}$, because the valid combinations are $HTTTTTTTTT$, $THTTTTTTTT$,...,$TTTTTTTTTH$.

Can somebody explain why is there a difference if we throw them all at once vs one by one, is my calulation for all at once even correct?

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me how you arrive at $45$ "combinations" in your first approach. Anyhow, the clou is that the rule "probability=#favourables divided by #possibles" only works if the outcomes are equiprobable. That rule is properly used in your second approach but cannot be used in your first approach. Further there is no essential difference between throwing at once or one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations for throwing the coins one by one are correct.  You should obtain the same answer if you throw them all at once.  Imagine marking each of the ten coins with a different number (or a distinct color) so that we can distinguish between them.  There are ten possible ways for one of those ten coins to be the one that turns up heads.  Since each of the ten coins has two possible outcomes, there are $2^{10}$ outcomes in the sample space.  Hence, the probability that exactly one heads is obtained is
$$\Pr(\text{exactly one head}) = \frac{10}{2^{10}}$$

Comment: But if coins are indistinguishable from one another the only difference between them is the index when we throwed them and if we throw them all at once there is no time difference to get them. Would my answer be correct if we would not distinguish them? How do we know that we have to distinguish between them ?

Comment: In probability, it makes sense to treat each object as distinguishable so that each event is equally likely to occur.  If you were to repeat the experiment, say, one million times, you would find that obtaining exactly one head occurs about ten times as often as obtaining no heads.  That is because there are ten coins which could be the only one that shows heads (even when we cannot distinguish between them), while there is only one outcome in which all the coins display tails.